# How to use if condition for an column in python

Tags: python, pandas

Having a column where i need to check for NaN rows using a conditional statement based on which i am looking to update a new column.

**Input Data**

```
Column1        Column2

AxBZ234
AYBY123
NaN
ZX23468
AC23YUK
NaN
```

**Script i have been using**

```
df['col2'] = df.apply(lambda x:'Col1 value Not available' if (x['col1'] == 'NaN') else 'Available',axis=1)
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1'].isna(), 'Col1 value Not available','Available')
```